# How to show Time only with AM/PM only in a SQL Query?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have the following problem, I am using SQL Server MS and below is my result. It looks simple but I cant figure it out.

My query:

```
SELECT  RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(26), Timein, 109), 14) from vwSignIn
```

Will give me this as a **9:12:16:597AM**

I want this **9:12:16 AM** as my result.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's one way you can do it:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), Timein, 108) + ' ' + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), Timein, 9), 2)
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3ac7e/1)

Comment: It worked perfectly! Thank you so much! I would vote up but I don't have enough rep yet.

Comment: @Apollo -- np, glad I could help!

Comment: -1 - Try a date past noon and you mix Military 24-Hour time with Meridian-AM/PM.  @AaronBertrand has the better, shorter, and more performant answer.

Answer (score 19):

Here's an approach with only one conversion:

```
SELECT RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(20), GETDATE(), 22), 11);
```

However you should consider formatting this on the client side, where string formatting is much more powerful and appropriate.

In SQL Server 2012, you will be able to use [`FORMAT()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx), which means you don't have to memorize all of these style numbers (but I still think you're better off doing this in the presentation layer when possible):

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'hh:mm:ss tt');
```

Just beware, `FORMAT()` is expensive relative to other approaches:

- [FORMAT() is nice and all, but…](http://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but)
- [FORMAT is a convenient but expensive function – Part 1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7144/sql-date-format-comparison-sql-format-sql-convert/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)
- [FORMAT is a convenient but expensive function – Part 2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7145/sql-date-format-comparison-computed-column-materialized-column/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)

Comment: WARNING: There is a difference between these two!  The first gives a blank-padding for hours < 10 (e.g. ' 3:33 PM'), the other uses a padded zero (e.g. '03:33 PM').  If you need to avoid a leading space for the hours before 10, then just wrap in an LTrim().  To avoid the padded Zero use this Format string instead: 'h:mm:ss tt'  To pad the first answer with a zero use this instead: SELECT RIGHT('0' + LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(CHAR(20), GETDATE(), 22), 11)), 11)  Yep, I think that about covers it.

Comment: Considering it's 2015 in the moment of writing this comment I highly upvote the FORMAT() option

Comment: @Zoran why? Did you know that not all shiny new things are better? http://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but

Comment: @Aaron thanks for letting me know. But thankfully for my situation where table function wont return more than 10 results (by design, and maximum ever could be 14 if Saturday and Sunday become work days) Format() is still a winner

Comment: @Zoran so that makes it a "winner" for *you*, in *that case*. What about everyone else?

Comment: I have upvoted it cause for me it is an elegant solution. Your note on performance should go into edit of your post for those for whom it would matter.

Answer (score 1):

I find this way to be a bit more elegant:

```
SELECT LTRIM(Right(REPLACE(CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),CAST(GetDate() as smalldatetime), 109),':00:000', ' '), 8));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT substring(convert(varchar(20), GetDate(), 9), 13, 5) + ' ' + substring(convert(varchar(30), GetDate(), 9), 25, 2)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you could explain your answer, it would be easier to understand, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I guess is:

```
select ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Timein, 100), '')
```